# Difference between ThreadStart and Action

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Does someone know the difference between

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(() =>
{
```

and

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
{
```

Comment: I stand corrected. Confused it with `Thread`, where I believe this is not the case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745420/why-does-dispatcher-begininvoke-unwrap-targetinvocationexception-for-threadstart

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be no difference. `ThreadStart` and `Action` are defined as

```
public delegate void ThreadStart();

public delegate void Action();
```

i.e., delegate with no parameters and no return value. So they are semantically the same.

---

However, I would use `Action` and not `ThreadStart`, as `ThreadStart` is strongly associated with `Thread` constructor, so the code with `ThreadStart` can hint to direct thread creation and therefore be slightly misleading.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there *is* a difference between `ThreadStart` and `Action` in the context of `BeginInvoke`.

They will both run the code within the delegate correctly, as Vlad has mentioned.

However, if an exception occurs within the delegate, `ThreadStart` results in a `TargetInvocationException`. But using `Action` gives you the correct exception from the delegate.

`Action` should be preferred for this reason.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28607015/4593760).