# How to force an application crash when AccessViolationException is detected

Tags: .net, exception, crash, crash-reports

We use an automated crash reporting tool (namely http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net) for generating crash reports.

So if a piece of unmanaged code fails by accessing a `NULL` pointer for example, the application crashes, the crash reporting tool activates and we get usable stack trace for diagnosing and grouping issues.

The problem is that .NET seems to interfere with crash handling in some cases. One sample is the following:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
{
  // Send message to unmanaged control for performing a specific task.
  User32.SendMessage(...);
}, DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

If the unmanaged component then fails with an access violation, internal .NET methods catch what should actually be a crash as `AccessViolationException` and rewrap it inside a `TargetInvocationException` first, then crashes (it would not do that without using method invocation).

This is highly inconvenient, because the native stack information is completely lost. What remains is the following stack, independently of where exactly the unmanaged part has failed:

```
kernelbase!RaiseException+0x6c
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x276
clr!RaiseTheException+0x86
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x30a
clr!RealCOMPlusThrow+0x2f
clr!ThrowInvokeMethodException+0xac
clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethod+0xa64
mscorlib_ni+0x2d37b1
mscorlib_ni+0x2cf92a
windowsbase_ni+0xd77b1
windowsbase_ni+0xd768a
windowsbase_ni+0xc2d5c
windowsbase_ni+0xc2c98
mscorlib_ni+0x302346
mscorlib_ni+0x302301
windowsbase_ni+0xc2b9b
windowsbase_ni+0xd640b
windowsbase_ni+0xd65ca
windowsbase_ni+0xd798b
windowsbase_ni+0xd78db
windowsbase_ni+0xd7756
windowsbase_ni+0xd768a
windowsbase_ni+0xd5cae
windowsbase_ni+0xd71e1
user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x100
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3ef
user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
windowsbase_ni+0xddca8
windowsbase_ni+0xd5636
windowsbase_ni+0xd5325
windowsbase_ni+0xb27d3
presentationframework_ni+0x2721b7
presentationframework_ni+0x271e0f
presentationframework_ni+0x271baa
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x152
clr!RunMain+0x1aa
clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x124
clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x614
clr!ExecuteEXE+0x4c
clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xdc
clr!_CorExeMain+0x4d
mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x10a
mscoree!ShellShim__CorExeMain+0x7d
mscoree!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x72
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

How can we prevent that and force the application to crash immediately when the unmanaged component fails?

Comment: CrashRpt is a C++ crash report library. How is it hooked into the .Net code to catch managed exceptions? Can you give an example of when you call the unmanaged code from .Net and it doesn't interfere with the `AccessViolationException`?

Comment: @ChrisO'Neill "How is it hooked into the .Net code to catch managed exceptions?" It's not actually hooked to catch any managed exceptions. It is catching unmanaged exceptions only. It doesn't interfere whenever BeginInvoke is not being used. So just remove the first and last line from the snippet above for a simple example.

Comment: Well, no, it catches managed exceptions as well.  That's how you got that stack trace.  Not good.  This library is but a bag o' bytes for what you want to accomplish.  You need a debugger to reliably detect an unmanaged exception that has a back-stop handler.  That exists, you need to play with the [DebugDiag utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933).  Maybe the [ClrMD library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx) can be useful, I haven't played with it enough.

Comment: So, the main process (the one that CrashRpt is actually hooked into) is unmanaged code, presumably C++. This process calls a .Net library, which then calls some unmanaged code using `BeginInvoke()`?

Comment: @ChrisO'Neill The main process is .NET, which calls a C++ library for installing the crash handler. The process (or other loaded .NET assemblies) then may later call unmanaged code or in this case invoke unmanaged functions by sending a message to an unmanaged control.

Comment: @HansPassant It catches unmanaged exceptions only at the point when they cause the application to crash. Other than that it doesn't invole with managed code. The utilities you mention seem to refer to inspecting the resulting crash dump, I am more interested in getting a better dump in the first place though. I have in fact been using DebugDiag, but even with that you cannot see the original source of the crash (unmanaged stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate 
{
    User32.SendMessage(...);
}, DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

The application should crash the way you want it to.

---

Most of the examples I've seen that call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` with an anonymous delegate use an `Action`.

- https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/tutorial-asynchronous-programming-async-and-await-for-beginners/
- http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

---

Why does this happen?

It seems that the CLR code, way down in:

```
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
```

invokes an `Action` directly, most other delegates are invoked using reflection.

The reflection mechanism will wrap exceptions in a `TargetInvocationException`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746677/4593760) to another question to explain.

---

Other special case delegates which will not wrap exceptions are:
`DispatcherOperationCallback` and `SendOrPostCallback`, though to work they have to be called with a single argument.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
    (SendOrPostCallback)(delegate(object o)
    {
        throw new AccessViolationException(o.ToString());
    }), "test");
```

Comment: I did not expect this do work. I made the change anyway, and it does indeed appear to make a difference (I will continue verifying this before I accept the answer though, need to be sure this works). Would you mind explaining why there would be any difference between a `delegate` and `Action`? I don't see why it would behave differently.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain my findings. Note that the suggested code snippet is slightly different.

Comment: I don't think this explanation is correct, the `ThreadStart` variant actually works perfectly fine (as long as the unmanaged part doesn't crash). So there must be some difference handling `Action` and `ThreadStart` internally, I find this hard to believe...

Comment: "the `ThreadStart` variant actually works perfectly fine (as long as the unmanaged part doesn't crash)". So ... it doesn't work perfectly fine? Don't be confused into thinking that `ThreadStart` must be the right way to call `BeginInvoke` just because it works most of the time. I've added some references for calling `BeginInvoke`. Feel free to go poking around in the CLR code to see what causes this behavior. I have and I could spend a lot of time finding the code that actually runs when `System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod()` is called, to get you a 'water tight' explanation.

Comment: Added an example showing that `ThreadStart` isn't the only delegate that only half works.

Comment: "just because it works most of the time." `ThreadStart` works all of the time. `Action` also works all of the time. Whether or not it fails depends on the unmanaged code (which doesn't care about the method used), the only (and surprising) difference is *how* these two variants fail. So you can't say that `ThreadStart` is the wrong way. Maybe I'll find a reason somehwhere...

Comment: `ThreadStart` does only work most of the time. In your example you need it to do two things. 1. Call the code in the delegate and 2. pass on any exceptions inside the delegate to the application and crash handler. It does 1 but not 2. Unmanaged exceptions only happen *sometimes* so `ThreadStart` 'works' *most of the time*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71784/discussion-between-floele-and-chris-oneill).

Comment: I found the implementation of InvokeMethod here
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/reflectioninvocation.cpp#L1347
lines 1661 - 1684 are relevant for the failing case. Not sure of the *exact* distinction between `ThreadStart` and `Action` but this might help.

Comment: Explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745420/why-does-dispatcher-begininvoke-unwrap-targetinvocationexception-for-threadstart

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to close the application after getting the exception.

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

Exit needs a parameter called exitcode. If exitcode=0 means there was no error. Supply a non-zero exit code to to reflect an error.